# Error Reading Multiple Segments from Mirthconnect

Tags: mirth

I am trying to read multiple segments (OBR) from HL7 message to database using Mirthconnect. The message is going through fine and Mirthconnect recording as Database write success, however I cannot see the data in the database. Can anyone please tell me how can I debug Mirthconnect connection with a database.

HL7 Message:

```
MSH|^~\&|AA|AA1|MSFT|AA1|20121203104758||OMG^O19|861232|T|2.4|||KA
PID|||P1563626|W981189|TEST^TEST^""^^MISS||20120910|F|||||||||||||||||||||""|L
PV1|||HOSP1||||||V2567697 ORC|WT|2R000112|||SD||||||||HOSP1 OBR|1|2R000112||TEST 1
ORC|WT|2R000445|||SD||||||||HOSP1 OBR|1|2R000445||TEST 2 ORC|WT|2R000399|||SD
||||||||HOSP1 OBR|1|2R000399||TEST 3
```

Comment: Please post a demo HL7 message with OBR...

Comment: MSH|^~\&|AA|AA1|MSFT|AA1|20121203104758||OMG^O19|861232|T|2.4|||KA
PID|||P1563626|W981189|TEST^TEST^""^^MISS||20120910|F|||||||||||||||||||||""|L
PV1|||HOSP1||||||V2567697
ORC|WT|2R000112|||SD||||||||HOSP1
OBR|1|2R000112||TEST 1
ORC|WT|2R000445|||SD||||||||HOSP1
OBR|1|2R000445||TEST 2
ORC|WT|2R000399|||SD||||||||HOSP1
OBR|1|2R000399||TEST 3

Comment: Your question needs refinement before anyone can help. So far, all I can derive is: you're somehow getting an HL7 message from somewhere, you're somehow attempting to read the OBR segments, you're somehow attempting to write some/all of the OBR data to a database, and you're somehow convinced that "the message is going through fine," despite the fact that the desired outcome is not being met. Please expand on each of those steps. How are you receiving this message? How are you attempting to read the OBR data? How are you attempting to write the OBR data to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Start off by creating a Javascript Transformer in your Mirth Channel. Copy your HL7 in the Source Transformer Message Translator window. YOu can create java script that would allow you to go through and iterate through the OBR segments.

```
var observation = {};
for each (obr in msg.OBR) {
 observation.type = obr['OBR.2'].toString();
}
```

Try the above mentioned and let us know.